# Typeorm when generating migrations with npm - Missing required argument: dataSource

Tags: node.js, typeorm

I've been breaking my head over creating migration files with Typeorm v0.3.17.
Everything works fine using yarn, but not using npm which seems confusing to me.

I keep getting this error message:

```
Missing required argument: dataSource
```

These are the scripts in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only --exit-child src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc -p .",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
    "migrate": "rm -rf build && npm run build && npm run typeorm migration:generate ./src/migrations/added-user-entity -d ./src/utils/data-source.ts",
    "db:push": "rm -rf build && npm run build && npm run typeorm migration:run -d ./src/utils/data-source.ts"
  }
```

data-source.ts

```
require("dotenv").config();
import "reflect-metadata";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import config from "config";

const postgresConfig = config.get<{
  host: string;
  port: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  database: string;
}>("postgresConfig");

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  ...postgresConfig,
  type: "postgres",
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: ["src/entities/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
  migrations: ["src/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}"],
  subscribers: ["src/subscribers/**/*{.ts,.js}"],
});
```

File structure:

```
backend
  ...
  src
    ...
    migrations
    utils
      data-source.ts
  package.json
```

command to generate and push migration:

```
npm run migrate && npm run db:push
```

am I missing something here?

Comment: resolved: I was missing the dashes in both typeorm scripts -> ....typeorm -- migration:....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this version, and I want to clarify this issue to others.

The point is that Typeorm has some changes in this version.
First of all, you have to pass the data source, which is the same old ormconfig file that was already a JSON file, but in this version, it must be a .ts file like this:

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

const connectionSource = new DataSource({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "your-db-username",
    password: "your-db-password",
    database: "your-db-name",
    synchronize: false,
    logging: false,
    entities: ["src/entity/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
    migrations: ["src/migration/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
    subscribers: ["src/subscriber/**/*{.js,.ts}"],
});

export default connectionSource;
```

Now you have to pass the datasource like this:

```
-d ./ormconfig.ts
```

So the scripts section in the package.json file would be as follow:

```
"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./ormconfig.ts",
"migration:create": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs migration:create ./src/migration/YOUR-MIGRATION-NAME",
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm migration:generate ./src/migration/YOUR-MIGRATION-NAME",
"migration:run": "npm run typeorm migration:run",
"migration:revert": "npm run typeorm migration:revert"
```

Just replace your arbitrary name instead of YOUR-MIGRATION-NAME in the above code.

**Note** that apparently [there is a bug in this version](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/9119#issuecomment-1158573329) that you have to mention the path of your migration file name like this after the migration:create and migration:generate scripts:

```
./src/migration/YOUR-MIGRATION-NAME
```

Otherwise, Typeorm would generate the migration file in your root project and can't run the migration:run as expected.

Hope this could help you.